# Strange Polymer bug, renders blank page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, polymer

I downloaded Google Polymer via Bower, and via zip but it doesn't work. It always renders a blank page.

I am using Polymer 0.5. Also, when I traverse the directory using chrome; **css and js files render, but the html file shows a blank page**. Is it a known bug?

How can it be fixed?

Comment: It doesn't work. What do I tell in that?

Comment: Css shows. Js shows. Html doesn't. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't view it that way. Per the site:

> While you’re working, you’ll need a basic HTTP server to serve your pages.

If you want a look on how to use it, use the [tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) for version 0.5 (the stable version at the moment).